# How (un)reasonable would it be to go backpacking to Egypt now?

Tags: safety, egypt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it safe to travel to Egypt in early 2012?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2624/is-it-safe-to-travel-to-egypt-in-early-2012)

Everyone has seen all the demonstrations in Egypt right now. I was wondering from practical perspective for a backpacker, does it really make a trip to Egypt more dangerous or difficult?