# Is it safe to travel to Cairo in July 2012?

Tags: safety, international-travel, egypt, cairo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it safe to travel to Egypt in early 2012?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2624/is-it-safe-to-travel-to-egypt-in-early-2012)

I am planning on travelling to Cairo this July but heard the elections will be in May with possibly a referendum on June 26th.  Do you think it will be still safe for me to visit Cairo during this period?

Comment: Similar question, recent time period that may be of interest to you: [Is it safe to travel to Egypt in early 2012?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2624/101)